# Adding to arrays

Tags: bash, array

I have this script

```
tests=()
igrepy -l $1 . | while read -r line
do
    // some processing
    tests+=("${second[0]}")
done
echo ${tests[@]}
```

I've checked that 'second' has a result and it does, however my echo returns a blank string. What has gone wrong here? This is on rhel6, 'igrepy' is an alias to a case insensitive grep that only search python files

Comment: That script fragment won't work; there's nothing before the `do` (eg a `while` or similar).

Comment: there is one, amended the op

Comment: The igrepy command is definitely returning results, and indeed after processing those results (into the 'second' var) it still has a non-empty value. Adding the declare statement returned "declare -a tests='()'", however I have put echos inside the loop and those came out too

Comment: Incidentally, any variable reference with `@` must be quoted for it to work as it should. So your last line should have been `echo "${tests[@]}"`. But that won't solve the underlying issue - see the answers from the duplicate questions for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is the standard "pipe creates subshell" with `bash`.

eg if you do

```
a=10
echo 100 | read a
echo $a
```

then `a` will still be set to `10` with bash.

In your case you have

```
igreppy | while read ...
do
  ....
done
```

and all the stuff inside that `while` loop will be in a subshell.

Instead it can be rewritten using process substitution

```
while read ...
do
  ....
done < <(igreppy ...)
```

Now no subshell is created for the `while` loop.